# Defining Windows Store app Resources in XAML

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-store-apps

```
<Page x:Class="Myprog.StartPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Myprog"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Height="36" Width="598" Margin="0 -5" Padding="2" BorderBrush="#FFE2E2E2">
            <Grid Background="#eee" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown_1">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <local:strConverter x:Name="sameera1"/>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ProductDesc,Converter={StaticResource sameera1}}" Margin="0,0,227,0" Foreground="Black" Padding="6,5,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

and then other elements...
```

---

in my code I have defined the class strConverter in the name space Myprog.StartPage. startPage is the page which contains the design.

I have use this resource strConverter to modify the value of the "ProductDesc".

```
<Grid.Resources>
   <local:strConverter x:Name="sameera1"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

when compiling below error message get displayed..

The name "strConverter" does not exist in the namespace "using:Myprog".

How I solve this??

Comment: What is the exact namespace definition for strConverter class?

Comment: The namespace is Myprog

Comment: Wait, now I see the problem. writing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to consume a resource, you need to declare a key for that resource.

So you should fix your resource declaration to this:

```
<Grid.Resources>
   <local:strConverter x:Key="sameera1"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Then name attribute has no meaning inside a ResourceDictionary.